# How to check flutter-desktop application already running on Windows? For using 1 instance launched

Tags: windows, flutter, desktop

How to check is flutter-desktop application already running on Windows? For using 1 instance launched.

Comment: I need to check has app been already running in windows. If it's running then skip or run new one

Comment: Updates? any updates?